# How to handle null as a key value in Hashtable in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, hashtable

As, I know Hash table doesn't allow null. 
How to handle it if I want to put key pair values?
Is there any other alternative in blackberry ??

Comment: you want to keep null as key?

Comment: You can't do that in `HashTable`. Replace the old deprecated to use `HashTable` for a `HashMap`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There is no HashMap in BlackBerry JDK

Comment: `Hashtable` does not support null as a key, whereas `HashMap` does. And if you are looking for `synchronized` collection then you can use `synchronizedMap`. `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>);`

Comment: @Jayamohan Multimap does not allow null keys because internally it uses a `Hashtable` to map keys to sets of values (Just tested). And besides, as its name implies, you can map several values to a single key, so even if it allowed null keys it is not a direct replacement for `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 7):

You can extend Hashtable with something like this

```
class NullKeyHashtable extends Hashtable {
    private static Object NULL = new Object();

    private Object nullToNull(Object key) {
        return key == null ? NULL : key;
    }

    public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
        return super.put(nullToNull(key), value);
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        return super.get(nullToNull(key));
    }

    ... 
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but you would have to override `containsKey` and `remove` as well.